# Replace org-mode drawer ellipsis with part of the folded content

Tags: org-mode, visibility, outline, fold

Consider the following org document where all the `PROPERTIES` drawers are unfolded :

```
* Books

** Book 1
:PROPERTIES:
:year: 1987
:author: Author 1
:publisher: Publisher 1
:END:

** Book 2
:PROPERTIES:
:year: 2010
:author: Author 2
:publisher: Publisher 2
:END:
```

When all drawers are collapsed, it looks like this :

```
* Books

** Book 1
:PROPERTIES:...

** Book 2
:PROPERTIES:...
```

**Is there a way to display a subset of the drawer's content in place or alongside the `...` ellipsis marker?**

For example, having the following folding output would offer much more value to a reader who wants to skim quickly through a list of books and focus only on their `year` property:

```
* Books

** Book 1
:PROPERTIES:year: 1987...

** Book 2
:PROPERTIES:year: 2010...
```

Here, I arbitrarily illustrated with `year` but the same could be done for any properties like `author` or `publisher`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want, but a built-in way to show only one or a few properties of an Org entry along with the heading is [Column View](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-View.html).

So to get a view similar to the one you want you can add a property drawer to the Books entry as follows:

```
* Books
:PROPERTIES:
:COLUMNS: %25ITEM %4year
:END:
```

Then calling `M-x org-columns RET` (`C-c C-x C-c` by default) with the cursor on the entry will show you something like this in vanilla Emacs (provided you fold the subheadings and scroll a bit):

[image: colview example]